# I'm recieving an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'" error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a straightforward Flask app based on a straightforward tutorial, and I'm trying to get my DB credentials out of the code and into an environment variable. I've got `DB_CONNECTION_STR` defined in `.env`, which is at the root of my application. The following is the top of my `database.py` file. This should be a simple fix; I might be missing an obvious typo.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import os

DB_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STR')

# These both print the right value:
print(DB_CONNECTION_STR)
print(os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STR'))

# This works:
db_connection_string = "mysql+pymysql://ehcazu8mvtvv4i44ghs3:pscale_pw_i960dmnsHwOCf3IWmKZi4AzOMVi1ZueGLYRiPZAy3i9@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/joviancareers?charset=utf8mb4"

# Trying either of these two gives me a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'"
# db_connection_string = DB_CONNECTION_STR
# db_connection_string = os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STR')

engine = create_engine(db_connection_string, connect_args={
  "ssl": {
    "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
  }
})
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taylor/src/jovian-carrers/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from database import load_jobs
  File "/home/taylor/src/jovian-carrers/database.py", line 17, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(db_connection_string,
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/taylor/src/jovian-carrers/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taylor/src/jovian-carrers/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 518, in create_engine
    u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Comment: Can you please add the full error message? Which object in particular is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

After beating my head against the wall for an hour I figure it out immediately after I post the question. I had to place the code to set up the engine inside of the function, and I'm assuming that when it was outside of it it didn't have access to the environment variables while the app was compiling?

**This doesn't work:**

```py
DB_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STR')

db_connection_string = DB_CONNECTION_STR

engine = create_engine(db_connection_string, connect_args = {
  "ssl": {
    "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
  }
})

def load_jobs():
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM jobs"))
    jobs = [dict(row) for row in result.all()]
    return jobs
```

**This works but required hardcoded credentials:**

```py
db_connection_string = "mysql+pymysql://ehcazu8mvtvv4i44ghs3:pscale_pw_i960dmnsHwOCf3IWmKZi4AzOMVi1ZueGLYRiPZAy3i9@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/joviancareers?charset=utf8mb4"

engine = create_engine(db_connection_string, connect_args = {
  "ssl": {
    "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
  }
})

def load_jobs():
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM jobs"))
    jobs = [dict(row) for row in result.all()]
    return jobs
```

**This works without the need for hard coded credentials:**

```
def load_jobs():
  DB_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STR')
  db_connection_string = DB_CONNECTION_STR
  engine = create_engine(db_connection_string, connect_args = {
    "ssl": {
      "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
    }
  })
  with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("SELECT * FROM jobs"))
    jobs = [dict(row) for row in result.all()]
    return jobs
```

Comment: Please remember that while your frustration is real, your post is going to stick around for _years_, please try to edit it to simply explain what was wrong and how to fix it without copious all-caps =)

Comment: Glad you found the solution in the end, however, If those hardcoded credentials are your actual credentials, you might want to change them.